# How to restore b2Body state after collision?

Tags: objective-c, ios, box2d

I have **2** bodies. **After they collide second body disappears**, and the **first** one must **go on it's move** in the in the same way as before the collision.

*How it looks now:*

1) I detect collision in contactListener::BeginContact(..) { };

2) Save the second body to delete , and the first to restore it's velocity and angle.

3)

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt {
int32 velocityIterations = 8;
int32 positionIterations = 1;
_world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
...
world->DestroyBody(secondBody);
firstBody->SetLinearVelocity(linearVelocityBeforeTouching);
firstBody->SetTransform(firstBody->GetPosition(), angleBeforeTouching );
...
}
```

*As a result the first body moves in the same direction, but it to rotate as after collision*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the two bodies collide you could do contact->SetEnabled(false) in the PreSolve of the collision listener to cancel the default collision response.